# How to set Option "DRI" "?" in Intel integrated graphics chipsets driver Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, xorg

I want to set options in the `20-intel.conf` file found in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, specifically for the "DRI" option.

Looking to the man page, the "DRI" option is "boolean", which to my mind means it either takes the value "true" or "false". (man page here: https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/intel.4.html)

Yet when finding info about this on the web, I find overwhelmingly that the suggestion is, for the example of using DRI3, to make the entry as "integer" (see for example Arch wiki:  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics)

So, my question?  Which is it?  Do I enter in the `20-intel.conf` file as `Option "DRI" "3"` or do I need to enter it as `Option "DRI" "true"`?

The man page seems to suggest the latter, but the ONLY examples I find on the web, seem to reference the Arch wiki page, and imply use of an integer.

Please, someone clarify this!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems the web advice to use Option "DRI" "n" (where n = 2 or 3) is incorrect according to man pages. 
Additional man pages found since the original posting are http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man4/intel.4.html
and 
 http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/xorg.conf.5.html

In the former link, as with the older man page link (see original post above), the "DRI" option is already enabled for hardware that can handle it:

> Option "DRI" "boolean"
>                 Disable or enable DRI support.
>
> ```
>           Default:   DRI   is  enabled  for  configurations  where  it  
>           is supported.
> ```

and in the latter, if one wanted DRI 2 enabled, one would make an entry in `20-intel.conf` as `Option "DRI2" "true"`, since it is disabled by default.

This is according to the `xorg.conf` man page (last link):

> Option "DRI2" "boolean"
>
> enable or disable DRI2. DRI2 is disabled by 
>                              default.